# Using Onsen-UI for Mobile Website and not for Mobile Application

Tags: angularjs, mobile, web, onsen-ui

Do you think it's good to use Onsen-UI for mobile websites and not for mobile application?
Was it not made for this purpose?
I have gone through their website and found nothing regarding mobile websites.

In case it does not work for mobile websites, may I know why?
Are there any specific mobile APIs that are not present in mobile browsers but its there in the application browser component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think it's good to use Onsen-UI for mobile websites and not for mobile application? Was it not made for this purpose?

I think that Onsen UI is originally created for developing mobile app. However, no matter happened when I adopted Onsen UI on my local web server and accessed with latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, though I'm not sure in case old browsers.

> Are there any specific mobile APIs that are not present in mobile browsers but its there in the application browser component?

I'd read their documentation and .js file. But no such APIs found. I think there are no such APIs.